# TypeScript - expressing types/constructors vs. instances of types

Tags: typescript

### Types

We could express using a type alias that we expect a type to be passed as an argument, like so:

```
type Type<T> = {
    readonly prototype: T
}

function getTypeArg<T>(t: Type<T>): void {
    ...
}
```

This fails because `123` is a primitive/instance and therefore doesn't have a prototype property.

```
getTypeArg(123);
```

This passes because it's a type and therefore has a prototype property.

```
getTypeArg(Number);
```

### Instances

The same is not so easy for instances.

```
function getInstance(inst: any): void {
    ...
}
```

Allows any instance to be passed

```
getInstance(123);
getInstance("Hello World");
```

But this also allows types to be passed, which we don't want

```
getInstance(String);
```

we should be able to fix this with a type alias

```
type Instance = {
    constructor: Function;
}

function getInstance(inst: Instance): void {
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't work, so the question is, why?

Comment: @m_callens that is the case when you are defining the constructor signature itself. Instances of objects have a `constructor` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terminology note: What you're calling a "type" would better be described as a "constructor".  The word "type" has a bunch of meanings, and in TypeScript you'd usually use it to mean something that does not exist as a runtime value at all.  Best to use "constructor", I think.

Anyway, the reason why it doesn't work is because all objects have a `constructor` property, even constructors:

```
console.log(String.constructor === Function) // true
```

I think only `null` and `undefined` fail to match your `Instance` interface.  If you really intend to exclude constructors, it would be better to define `Instance` as "a thing with no `prototype`", like this:

```
type Instance = {
  constructor: Function;
  prototype?: never;  // prototype can be missing or undefined, that's it    
}
```

And it should work more like what you intend:

```
getInstance(123); // okay
getInstance("Hello World"); // okay
getInstance(String); // error as desired
getInstance(null); // error as desired I hope
getInstance(undefined); // error as desired I hope
```

Hope that helps; good luck.

Comment: The only point where this fails is functions, as functions have a constructor (even if they're not used as constructors) but if you don't consier a function an instance, then it works perfectly.